# Symfony: No route found for get http://localhost/SymfonyCRUD/web/app_dev.php/hello

Tags: php, symfony

I am beginning to learn Symfony and I ran into this problem >>> Symfony: No route found for get http://localhost/SymfonyCRUD/web/app_dev.php/hello. I have ensured that the parameters I entered into my routing.yml file are correct but the error still persists from my browser.
**ROUTING.YML**

```
custom_book_homepage:
    pattern:  /hello
    defaults: { _controller: CustomBookBundle:Default:index }
```

**CONTROLLER FILE**

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('CustomBookBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Please what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 comments on your yaml:

1. From the Symfony docs the pattern param must be path
2. Your yaml is invalid yaml, so probably you will have a parsing error.

Try this:

```
custom_book_homepage:
  path: /hello
  defaults: 
    _controller: "CustomBookBundle:Default:index"
```